# how to structure unseen count and messages for group chat firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

unseen messages are unique for every member of the group.should I create and update last added message and unseen count for every member of the group. i am little confused how to structure the group in realtime database.my question is if I have to update unseen count for every member then I have to check who is active in the group at the moment and loop through every member to update unseen count and last messages.how to approach this group creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically track the key or timestamp of the last message each user has seen. From that you can then create a query that gets only messages from there on.

If you want a count of the unread message count for each user, you could store their "last seen key" in the database, and use that to determine the unseen message count for each of them by either running a query for each of them, or (better) by determining the oldest unseen, running a query for that, and then calculating the rest in code.

Of course you could also store the unseen message count for each user in the database, in which case I would use a Cloud Function that increments the counters on every message that is added, and decrements it whenever an (older) message is removed.

Comment: I am downloading chat messages only when user entering at the chat page.for unseen count and last message is stored in separate node for one to one chat.i don't want to download all the messages outside of chat page to reduce cost.am I doing right.

Comment: If you use the first approach I outlined, that is perfectly feasible. You can then run a query with `orderByKey().startAt(lastSeenKey)` to only get the new items. If you're having trouble with this, I recommend posting a new question showing the code of what you tried.

Comment: Yes iam using your query to download only new items but with little change.i only download new items when user A enter into user B chat page.i don't download recent chat msgs in main activity and calculate unseen count.

Comment: Instead of downloading all recent messages in main activity.i only download recent messages when user particularly opens one chat page to reduce cost. I saved unseen count and last msg in seprate node and download that only to display at chat list.i wanted to do that same for group.